# grouping a dataset in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have  a data set described below: I need to group the rows with following conditions:

1. if the times are continuous then group rows to show first in_time and last out_time and sum the total mins.
2. If the times are not continuous then keep the rows as it is.

   `ID    In_time           Out_Time           Total_Mins  seq_num`

   `A     4/1/2014 10:00    4/5/2014 10:00      5760         1`

   `B     4/2/2014 08:30    4/3/2014 08:30      1440         1`

   `C     4/3/2014 09:00    4/3/2014 16:30      450          1`

   `C     4/3/2014 16:30    4/4/2014 10:00      1050         2`

   `C     4/4/2014 10:00    4/6/2014 18:00      3360         3`

   `D     4/3/2014 02:00    4/4/2014 05:00      180          1`

   `D     4/5/2014 06:00    4/5/2014 17:00      660          2`

I have tried using partition, first_value and last_value function to get the rows below is my query to get the rows.

```
`select r1.id
       ,r1.in_time as in_time
       ,r2.out_time as out_time
       ,r1.totalTimeMins + r2.totalTimeMins as totalMins
from rdata r1 
  inner join rdata r2 on r1.id = r2.id 
                         and r1.seqNum =r2.seqNum - 1
                         and r1.out_time = r2.in_time`
```

Can somebody suggest how to get the 1 row for continuous time frame and other rows as it is if they do not have continuous time frame?

Answer (score 0):

try this and let me know,

```
  SELECT DISTINCT t.id,
         first_value(t.in_time) OVER ( PARTITION BY t.id ORDER BY t.seq_num ) in_time,
         first_value(t.out_time) OVER ( PARTITION BY t.id ORDER BY t.seq_num DESC ) out_time,
         SUM(t.total_mins) OVER ( PARTITION BY t.id )  total_mins
    FROM rdata t
```

Comment: This will not satisfy the second condition and it will group all the rows irrespective of the time frame.

Answer (score 0):

### Querying a NEXT Record in ANSI SQL Without an Analytical Function

Some of the more advanced RDBMS systems have fancy built-in functions such as analyticals and stuff.  I don't know what system you are using, but you can accomplish the task with some simple ANSI standard SQL.  Here's what I'm thinking...

> In this case, we query the same table twice and join it to itself, but shifting the indexes/join keys so that the first record lines up with the one that follows it.  We use an OUTER join because as in the sample data, not all categories have more than one time entry.

```
    [SQL Fiddle][1]
```

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```sql
    CREATE TABLE punch_clock_timecard
       (`ID` varchar(1), `In_time` datetime, `Out_Time` datetime, 
        `Total_Mins` int, `seq_num` int);
    
    INSERT INTO punch_clock_timecard
       (`ID`, `In_time`, `Out_Time`, `Total_Mins`, `seq_num`)
    VALUES
        ('A', '2014-04-01 00:00:00', '2014-04-05 00:00:00', 5760, 1),
        ('B', '2014-04-01 22:30:00', '2014-04-02 22:30:00', 1440, 1),
        ('C', '2014-04-02 23:00:00', '2014-04-03 06:30:00', 450, 1),
        ('C', '2014-04-03 06:30:00', '2014-04-04 00:00:00', 1050, 2),
        ('C', '2014-04-04 00:00:00', '2014-04-06 08:00:00', 3360, 3),
        ('D', '2014-04-02 16:00:00', '2014-04-03 19:00:00', 180, 1),
        ('D', '2014-04-04 20:00:00', '2014-04-05 07:00:00', 660, 2);
```

**Query 1**:

```
   select pct1.id, pct1.out_time, pct2.in_time as next_in_time,
          pct1.seq_num, pct2.seq_num as next_seq_num
     from punch_clock_timecard pct1
     left outer join punch_clock_timecard pct2
       on pct1.id = pct2.id
      and (pct1.seq_num + 1) = pct2.seq_num
    order by pct1.id asc, pct1.seq_num asc, pct2.seq_num asc;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d5dc1/20/0)**:

```
| ID |                     OUT_TIME |                 NEXT_IN_TIME | SEQ_NUM | NEXT_SEQ_NUM |
|----|------------------------------|------------------------------|---------|--------------|
|  A | April, 05 2014 00:00:00+0000 |                       (null) |       1 |       (null) |
|  B | April, 02 2014 22:30:00+0000 |                       (null) |       1 |       (null) |
|  C | April, 03 2014 06:30:00+0000 | April, 03 2014 06:30:00+0000 |       1 |            2 |
|  C | April, 04 2014 00:00:00+0000 | April, 04 2014 00:00:00+0000 |       2 |            3 |
|  C | April, 06 2014 08:00:00+0000 |                       (null) |       3 |       (null) |
|  D | April, 03 2014 19:00:00+0000 | April, 04 2014 20:00:00+0000 |       1 |            2 |
|  D | April, 05 2014 07:00:00+0000 |                       (null) |       2 |       (null) |
```

You can wrap this query within another SQL statement which picks through and runs the final evaluations (i.e., `OUT_TIME` vs. `NEXT_IN_TIME`...)

Onward!

Answer (score 0):

revised one...

```
SELECT k.id, MIN(k.in_time) in_time, MAX(k.out_time) out_time, SUM(k.total_mins) total_mins
  FROM (
SELECT a.*, DECODE(b.seq,a.seq_num,'continuous'||a.id,'not continuous'||a.seq_num) flag
  FROM rdata a,
       ( SELECT t.id tid, t.seq_num seq
           FROM rdata t, rdata s
          WHERE t.id = s.id
           AND t.out_time = s.in_time 
         UNION
         SELECT t.id tid, s.seq_num seq
           FROM rdata t, rdata s
          WHERE t.id = s.id
           AND t.out_time = s.in_time ) b
 WHERE a.id = b.tid(+)
   AND a.seq_num = b.seq(+) ) k
 GROUP BY k.id, k.flag  
 ORDER BY 1,2,3
```